# ant not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ant

I have installed ant on Ubuntu 12.10 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

But when i try to access, i am getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/ant: 1: eval: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu related helps please ask in IRC Channel , you will get faster response there .

Comment: @Nishant : It looks like a ant issue

Comment: I also downloaded the binary package and tried: /apache-ant-1.9.0/bin$./ant . I get the same error

Comment: How do you run the command? Only by typing `ant` in console?

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała yes. Please let me know if i am doing wrong. I am expecting it should tell "build.xml" not found

Comment: I think that it may be some error with core ant but try to create simple build.xml which echos something and run it in this way `ant <target> -f"<absolute path to file>"`

Comment: when i try the same on my centos :[root@cent01 ~]# ant

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!

Build failed

But the above error comes when i try to use on my ubuntu 12.10